# Play mp4 video from url

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using `VideoView` to play video from url. When I run app it gives error `Can't play this video` with below msg in logcat

```
    Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side:java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:aklearningsolutions.com/video/Nursery%20Rhymes.mp4

Unable to open content: aklearningsolutions.com/video/Nursery%20Rhymes.mp4
                                                          java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
                                                              at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1095)
                                                              at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1069)
                                                              at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1023)
```

below is my activity file

```
package com.dp.videostore.Activity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.dp.videostore.R;

public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    VideoView videoView;
    String url = "aklearningsolutions.com/video/Nursery Rhymes.mp4";
    MediaController mc;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        try {
            mc = new MediaController(this);
            mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
            mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
            videoView.setMediaController(mc);
            Uri link = Uri.parse(url.replace(" ","%20"));
            videoView.setVideoURI(link);
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Below is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dp.videostore.Activity.PlayerActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/video_view"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

When i hit video link in web browser, video play very well in browser

Comment: Have you tried downloading a file and playback from a local disk? Do web server redirects to somewhere else so url is not a real link to mp4?

Comment: Your url doesn't have `http://` in front of it...

Comment: your link needs to be like this http://aklearningsolutions.com/video/Nursery 20Rhymes.mp4

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks to your suggestion, adding 'http://'  it is working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the protocol into your URL. As it is, Android thinks you are using a ContentProvider

```
String url = "http://aklearningsolutions.com/video/Nursery Rhymes.mp4";
```